# Program is running well when use int but when I use char it starts skipping line

Tags: arrays, c, char, scanf

I am new to c coding, my program is running well when use `int` data type, but when I use `char` it starts skipping line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    char k[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("enter your character for line %d: \n", i);
        scanf("%c", &k[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("your character for line %d are %c \n", i, k[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wots with all the stars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you press Enter you are writting 'new line' character to program's input.
And because it's character, `%c` is reading it.

Specifier `%c` doesn't consume spaces like other specifiers, so you have to explicitly tell `scanf` to skip whitespaces, by adding space before `%c`, so you will have `" %c"` as format.

More details might be here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240807/2416941

**EDIT:** Be aware that this way you can't read space or tabs from user's input.